# Configuration files per environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project with several environments (Local,Development,Main,Prod,Live) that have several config files (Web, ConnectionStrings Windsor, Smtp, Appsettings, Nlog, etc).

The current strategy used is to have one of these config for each branch and to maintain the configs by hand and not to merge any changes.

What are the more elegant options for storing and deploying config files in this sort of set up?

Comment: This probably belongs at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Too many exchanges these days!

Answer (score 0):

Generally I tried to keep most of these settings in the appSettings (even though I know that's not the "official" right place for them).  Then I break the appSettings out into an environment.config file, and have the appSetting element in the web.config reference that through the configSource attribute.

When I setup a new environment, I manually setup the environment.config file for that environment.  When, when I deploy a new release, I exclude the environment.config file from teh deployment so that the environment-specific version stays in place.

This lets you deploy new copies of the web.config to include project-related changes, while keeping all of your truly environment-specific settings in a seperate place.

Comment: using msbuild to switch in the files?

Comment: yeah, you definitely could use MSbuild to swap the files, but I didn't want to make any assumptions about your build environment.  Anyhow, I use TeamCity and NAnt for builds, but I stil use this approach for configs, just because it's so simple.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to use [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) (from Microsoft) for the deployment of your web app. When you run the deployment, you can specify a site specific parameter file which will be used the replace several values in the web.config file.

For deployment, WebDeploy uses a deployment packge, which Visual Studio or msbuild can create.

That way, we have a single deployment package that we can first deploy on a test system, run through several tests and then, when it passes the test, deploy without changes on several servers. Each server has its local parameter file that hardly ever changes and contains the site specific values.

Answer (score 0):

store them on a file server that has the same name in all environments.  I am not familiar with all of the configs, but most have ways of doing this.  The only problem with this approach is usually dev/local which often share a file server so you have to change the local by hand.

If you actually can't point the configs to a file server, a less elegant solution would be to  pull them down via a bat file at deployment or start up.  seems like there are alot of options rather than maintaining by hand, that is error prone.